# Playing hd video from a server to 10 android tablets in LAN via wi-fi

Tags: router, wifi, video, android

I am working on a project where I will have 10 android tablets and a server with videos
in 720p quality. All of these will be in the same LAN. I want to be able to play videos from this server on the tablets, which are connected via wifi.

I think it could be achievable with just one single router, but can you please guide me, which things should I be aware of and which parameters to look at?

Thank you in advance

Carl

Answer (score 1):

I think 10 devices connected to a wireless router is likely to be pushing the capacity of the device, video or no video (naturally, it depends on the router/access point. If it's a Belkin SOHO thing then you'll be lucky to get that). The best thing to do is see if your application can balance quality over speed (that is, the faster the connection, the higher the quality. If more clients connect to the stream the video quality will have to drop slightly to keep playing).

What is your router model?

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. i have no router yet, i want to get to know as much as possible before buying to prevent a failure. if it wont work, i will try the sacrifice of video quality. or to use another network solution

Answer (score 1):

Well depending on your encoding for 720p this project might prove to be pretty hard to achieve .
You have the following obstacles :

1. wireless g transfer rates 2mbs vs encoding of the video and the broadband of the router
2. encoding for 720 p video
3. router bands and frequency\ channels used vs other wireless routers in the area .

After you resolve connection issues , you should be aware that there is some bandwidth reserve for caching of videos - processing for the tablets .

I would recommend that you study the encoding video codec very well and choose the best one for you situation .

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. i will study the codecs and if nothing else, i will drop the video quality (its not that important). or i will try to find out some other network solution than just one router. dont you have some suggestions?

Comment: I would go for a dual band router from one of companies : Netgear , D-link , Assus . Dual band would bring a great advantage as it offers separate bandwidths and channels . http://reviews.cnet.com/routers/d-link-amplifi-hd/4505-3319_7-34468657.html - this would be one of the candidates , don't forget to check if it does have QoS and VoIP , video streaming prioritization inbuilt , so you won't have issues if the connection is used for something else (from experience it can happen )  . And depending on the tablets used you must settle between wireless G(compatibility) N(speed ).

Comment: thank you again! wish i will be able to help you somehow back in the future. have a nice day